# When settting the CultureInfo error is returned

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cultureinfo, sharepoint-online

I am developing a SharePoint Online add-in in ASP.NET MVC 5. I have three resource files with three languages that I want `CultureInfo` to read when the corresponding language code is returned from Shareoint. This is my code:

In the `ActionResult Index:`

```
    var returnedLangCode= WorkPlanRepo.LangSettings();
        if (returnedLangCode!= "")
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(returnedLangCode);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(returnedLangCode);

        }
        else
        {

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en");
        }
```

The method returning sharePoint Lang settings in my class workPlanRepo:

```
   public string LangSettings()
    {
        CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        var twoLetterLangName = currentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

        return twoLetterLangName;
    }
```

I hev three Resource files, Default is English, then I have Swedish and Danish. All Resources are set to Public. In the view I reach for the resource file like this:

```
  @Html.Label(CMP.ArbetsplanWeb.App_LocalResources.GlobalRes.ResetCalender ,new { @class = "btn btn-default", id = "clearCal" })
```

This is the errormessage:

When settting the CultureInfo error is returned. Wanted to insert img, but the upload tool dosen´t seem to work properly.

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "CMP.ArbetsplanWeb.App_LocalResources.GlobalRes.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "CMP.ArbetsplanWeb" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

```
Line 75:         public static string ResetCalender {
Line 76:             get {
Line 77:                 return ResourceManager.GetString("ResetCalender", resourceCulture);
Line 78:             }
Line 79:         }
```

> MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "CMP.ArbetsplanWeb.App_LocalResources.GlobalRes.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "CMP.ArbetsplanWeb" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.]
>      System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName)

I havent registerd anything in `web.config` or `Global.asax`. I now I must be doing something wrong. But cant figure out what. I found diffrent guides and docs on this but cant figure out how to useit properly.

Thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I was using a ASP.NET folder for my resources. When I changed to a regular folder everything worked.